# Fail2ban restarts every day

Tags: fail2ban

In my server I can see that the fail2ban restarts every day. While checking the internet I can see that the logrotate causes this. I have disabled the logrotate of fail2ban by removing the fail2ban files from logrotate.d . Also checked all cron jobs and even checked /etc/cron.daily . But the issue still persist. Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: @SvW i guess because banns are lost on fail2ban when it's restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure you fixed the [Problem](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=301139) with logrotate?

Taken from [1.Answer](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-844458-start-0.html):

In `/etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban` the line:

```
/usr/bin/fail2ban-client reload 1>/dev/null || true
```

Should be changed to:

```
/usr/bin/fail2ban-client set logtarget /var/log/fail2ban.log 1>/dev/null || true
```

*In the case of fail2ban reload does more than just reload the config.*

Comment: I have completely disabled the fail2ban logrotate service